# Why can't I SaveChanges() to my DbContext like this?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I had some code for inserting some rows that wasn't working:

```C#
using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext()) {
    foreach (Order o in FormOrders) { //That's a List<T> that got generated based on a web form
        context.Orders.Add(o);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I finally figured out how to make it work:

```C#
foreach (Order o in FormOrders) {
    context.Orders.Add(o);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, I realize that's not very efficient. Granted, the most Orders that will ever get inserted at one time is about 40, but I'm still interested in using best practices as much as I can.

I'm guessing code snippit #1 didn't work because `o` is out of scope of the point that `SaveChanges()` is called, but I don't understand how this works well enough to be sure, and I definitely don't understand it enough to figure out what a better way is.

Also, I have heard that you're supposed to use a new instance of your DbContext for every row, which would be even less efficient to implement in the above case. Is that true?

**EDIT**

DISREGARD THIS QUESTION. Both versions seem to work. I don't know what the problem was. I'm not deleting it because someone else might find some of the comments/answers useful.

Comment: What happens when you set `o` to a temp variable right after the `foreach` statement, and then add the temp variable to your `context.Orders` collection?  If you call `SaveChanges()` outside the `foreach` loop, does it save?

Comment: What error(s) are you getting? Is the first line of your first snippet supposed to read `using (MyDbContext context = new DbContext()) {`?

Comment: Never mind. Maybe I'm crazy. Code #1 seems to be working now. I swear I tried this all day yesterday and absolutely nothing got inserted. It never threw any errors, just did nothing. And @AntP, my `using` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which context you are using but, LINQ to SQL SubmitChanges behaves differently than LINQ to Entitie's SaveChanges in the light of optimistic concurrency conflicts.

**SubmitChanges** = DataContext
**SaveChanges** = ObjectContext

```
using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext()) {
    foreach (Order o in FormOrders) { //That's a List<T> that got generated based on a web form
        context.Orders.Add(o);
    }
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are dealing with closures here.

Try if this code works for you:

```C#
using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext())
{
    foreach (Order o in FormOrders)
    {
        Order localCopy = o;
        context.Orders.Add(localCopy);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In short, Your Add() method will be executed only ONCE. Due to delayed execution only the last item of the loop will be added.

*(Quote from Jon's article linked below)*

> **What are closures?**
>
> To put it very simply, closures allow you to encapsulate some
>   behaviour, pass it around like any other object, and still have access
>   to the context in which they were first declared. This allows you to
>   separate out control structures, logical operators etc from the
>   details of how they're going to be used. The ability to access the
>   original context is what separates closures from normal objects,
>   although closure implementations typically achieve this using normal
>   objects and compiler trickery.

The experts will explain this much better than I ever could:

- Microsoft's **Eric Lippert**: [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)
- Google's **Jon Skeet**: [The Beauty of Closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure ? DbSet.Add is synchrone so there is no closure problem.

Comment: @remibourgarel: Not completely sure to be honest. I am afraid I have not yet understood the concept to its full length. But I had been experiencing all sorts of weird behavior in similar scenarios and ReSharper gives me warnings for nearly every third loop I write. That's why this was my first thought.

Comment: Most of the time is when there is deferred execution because you're using lambda expression (you create your lambda in the loop but you execute it outside of it, like we do with a linq expression)